# no such module ssziparchive , after using cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ssziparchive

I was trying to install ssziparchive framework using cocoa pods and faced the following problem: after appearingly successful install I get the error, that in

```
import SSZipArchive
```

no such module 'SSZipArchive'

here is the pod file:

```
    platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

target 'archivetest' do
    pod 'SSZipArchive', '1.0.1'
end

target 'archivetestTests' do

end
```

Has anyone got the same problem? and if yes, how one can fix it?

Comment: @SnarfSnarf sorry, it seems, I can't up vote now, need some more points, will try again later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are opening the `.xcodeproj`.  Close Xcode instead open the `.xcworkspace` file

Comment: yes, you were right, I was somehow choosing .xcodeproj all the time